# Secure method for supporting partial string matching on an encrypted database field

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption

I am writing a web application that use PHP + MySQL. I know that both PHP and MySQL can perform data encryption. I have also read that encrypting the data in the PHP level is more preferred in terms of security. But now I face this problem: I would like to encrypt the address field of some user data. But in the webpage written using PHP, I would like to support partial string matching of the address field. My current solution is to encrypt the data in the MySQL level and then do the searching like this:

```
// PHP code for inserting data into database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('', AES_ENCRYPT('" . $addr . "', UNHEX('" . $hexstring . "')))", $link);

// PHP code for partial string matching
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE AES_DECRYPT(address, UNHEX('" . $hexstring . "')) like '%Street%'", $link);
```

Is there a more secure way that performs the encryption in the PHP level instead of the MySQL level? What I can think of is to retrieve all records, decrypt the data in PHP and perform the matching, but it will be very slow. AES is not a must, any encryption/decryption method is ok as long as it is secure enough.

Comment: I was going to suggest a partial index, but seeing how you use wildcards on both sides, no index can actually be used.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what exactly you're encrypting the value for, what your attack scenario is and who you want to protect against.

Comment: @deceze: Indeed I am not looking for solutions that can survive for deliberate attacks, but I just want to find a reasonably secure solution that can encrypt the personal data so that if the database data is being stolen, people will not be able to read the data directly or easily (privacy concern), and attackers won't be able to decrypt the data with minimum effort.

Comment: @LaBird That's lots of pain for little gain. As long as the application can decrypt the database, most breaches will be able to extract the key from the application. I'd rather put my effort into storing and processing sensitive data on a server with as little access surface as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to encrypt the address field of some user data. But in the webpage written using PHP, I would like to support partial string matching of the address field.

This is the difficulty with encrypted databases. You have to choose between one of the two:

1. Experimental academic designs, such as order-revealing encryption, that lack the semantic security we normally expect when encrypting data.
2. Authenticated encryption with [blind indexes and bloom filters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql).

If you'd prefer the latter approach (I do), the process is somewhat straightforward:

1. Generate a separate key for each partial match you wish to support.
2. Create a function that deterministically transforms the plaintext into a pre-hash message (e.g. the street number and first letter of the name of the road (`123 Main Street` => `123m`, etc.)
3. Use a secure keyed hashing construct, such as `hash_hmac()` or `hash_pbkdf2()`, on the output of step 2.
4. (Optional): Truncate the output of step 3 to a small number of bytes (e.g. 8 hex characters). This means more false positives in your search results, but less uniquely distinguishing facts that can be learned about your plaintext from an adversary who has gained access to your database server.
5. Store that alongside the ciphertext, which should itself be [encrypted securely](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide).

Of course, all of this is in vain if your encryption key is stored on the same hardware as the database server. An attacker capable of accessing your database (e.g. SQL injection) can escape to the filesystem and steal the keys, unless the webserver and database are on separate hardware.